# Static webpage redirect http to https using Google loadbalancer

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to implement URL redirects from http to https as described by [https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management][1] but I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have a storage bucket with a very simple HTML page.
I have an external HTTP load balancer in front of it. Static IP address. SSL cert. I managed to connect everything so that both http and https requests for the site load the contents of the bucket.

I tried to add the HTTP redirect as per the document:

1. Changes 'Host and path rules' from 'Simple' to 'Advanced...'.
2. The default route still points to the bucket
3. I added a new route. Host is 'www.example.com. The default path rule points to the bucket. The second path rule matches /* and does a prefix/HTTPS redirect as described in the above link.

Once the config is saved, either http or https requests to www.example.com results in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

What am I doing wrong? Really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
[Backend configuration][2]
[Frontend configuration][3]
[Host and path rules][4]
[Redirect path rule][5]


[1]: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkhUF.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYst0.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsTOX.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tEDE.png
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI - someone in Google Groups pointed out that I needed 2 load balancers. 1 to terminate the HTTPS traffic and the second to redirect the HTTP traffic. Works like a charm.